# REACT - Clicking on Resume header doesn't download resume pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm creating a portfolio website using React. I would like for it to automatically download the pdf file when clicking the resume link. However, it is not working. I'm using npm and the file is not downloading through localhost.

Tried adding a link to and download tag. Also moved the pdf file to my public folder.

On my App.js page:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Layout, Header, Navigation, Drawer, Content, download} from 'react-mdl';
import Main from './components/main';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="demo-big-content">
    <Layout>
        <Header className="header-color" title="Title" scroll>
            <Navigation>
                <Link to="http://localhost:3000/">Home</Link>
                <Link to="DeveloperResFINALReactNot.pdf" download>Resume</Link>
                <Link to="/aboutme">About Me</Link>
                <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </Navigation>
        </Header>
```

On my resume.js page:

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';


class Resume extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> Resume Page </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Resume;
```

Expected to download resume file upon clicking, instead it is just returning a blank white page.

UPDATE: Solved problem by replacing it with:

```
<a href="DeveloperResFINALReactNot.pdf" download>Resume</a>
```

But if anybody knows how to do this using the Link to tag it would be much appreciated!

Comment: why do you need to do it with link? your solution is proper. link is for routing components not for downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use tags like  the link will get opened in a new window but you have to download it from there.

If you want to download the file directly, you can use the following NPM package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<a href="DeveloperResFINALReactNot.pdf" download>Resume</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are serving static file from a server, setting response header should do the trick

For NodeJS server

```
var pdf = fs.createReadStream('./path-to-file-location/DeveloperResFINALReactNot.pdf');

app.get('/downloadPdf', function(req, res){
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=DeveloperResFINALReactNot.pdf');
  pdf.pipe(res);
});
```

From Client side

```
<a href="/downloadPdf">downloadPdf</a>
```